# C#:ZedGraph Zooming all panes simultaneously

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am using zedgraph to plot my data. I have a `MasterPane` and it has three `GraphPanes`. After drawing data I want to zoom all graphs simultaneously. Any suggestion?

```
    MasterPane master = zgc.MasterPane;
    master.Title.IsVisible = true;
    master.Margin.All = 10;
    master.Fill = new Fill(Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 255), 45.0f);
    master.PaneList.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPanes; i++)
    {
        string title = null;
        GraphPane pane = new GraphPane();
        master.Add(pane);
        if (i == 0)
            title = "";
        if (i == 1)
            title = "";
        if (i == 2)
            title = "";
        if (i >= 3)
            title = "" + (i - 2).ToString();
        GraphSettings.PanelProperties(pane, title);
    }
    zgc.AxisChange();
    using (Graphics g = frm.CreateGraphics())
    {
        master.SetLayout(g, PaneLayout.SquareColPreferred);
        master.SetLayout(g, PaneLayout.SingleColumn);
        master.AxisChange(g);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `.IsSynchronizeXAxes` and `z.IsSynchronizeYAxes` property of the ZedGraph control:

```
zgc.IsSynchronizeXAxes = true;
zgc.IsSynchronizeYAxes = true;
```